# ajax voting for custom post type

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, ajax

Hi guys I have been recently working on a project which includes the voting mechanism. I have already build a plugin for regular post which calls the ajax voting for any single post. but I also have to do the same for CPT.

for regular post I am using the `is_single()` condition. can anyone tell me how do I grab the custom post. I have tried `is_singular('custom_post_type_name')`

but its not working. I have a *single.php* for regular and single-*runner_projects.php* for the CPT.

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'post_love_display', 99 );
```

function post_love_display($content) {

```
$love_text = '';

if (is_single()) {

    //reciving the meta value form post content.

    $love = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'post_love', true );

    if (empty($love)) {

        $love = 0;

    } else {

        $love;

    }

    $love_text = '<p class="love-received"><a class="love-button" href="' . admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php?action=post_love_add_love&post_id=' . get_the_ID() ) . '" data-id="' . get_the_ID() . '"></a><span id="love-count">' . $love . '</span></p>'; 

}

return $content.$love_text;
```

}

here is my code for the php plugin:

Comment: Where and how are you using `is_single()`? Please include the code that's the issue.

Comment: so what about for the cpt?